# .avi file video not play in MPMoviePlayerController ios player

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play *avi* formatted video files.
The audio works, but the video doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: Important

The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit

Comment: Use can use  AVPlayerViewController
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` only supports *.mov, .mp4,.mpv, and .3gp* and is **deprecated**.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller):

> The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9.
>   (The MPMoviePlayerController class is also formally deprecated.) To
>   play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the
>   AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the
>   AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

You should use **AVPlayerViewController**:

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

let videoPath = "https://video.avi"
let videoURL = URL(string: videoPath)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player?.play()
}
```

or just add **AVPlayer** in as a subview:

```
let videoURL = URL(string: videoPath)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

**it supports the following audio/video formats:**
.mpeg, .mpeg-2-video, .avi, .aifc-audio, .aac-audio, .mpeg-4, .au-audio, .aiff-audio, .mp2, .3gpp2, .ac3-audio, .mp3, .mpeg-2-transport-stream, .3gpp, .mpeg-4-audio

Comment: Ny way to detect whether a remote URL is playable or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot play .avi file using MPMoviePlayerController in ios.

As  .avi format  contents are not possible to decode the video on a iOS device.

Comment: I want to play .avi file (with Audio&Video) in ios,  So any player available for this? or player library like ijkmediaplayer(this one not support avi)

Comment: I able to play audio but not video